# What has happened with the pH-meter?

Tags: ph, equipment

The glass sensor has became red inside like something melted. I stored it in a liquid with pH that mentioned in the manual. What is that and why could that happen, how often that happens with pH-meters?
(10 bucks pH-meter from China)
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Be more precise ! What is the meaning of "red like something melted" ? Which "liquid" did you use to store your electrode ? How long did you store it ? What is the "pH mentioned in the manual" ? What goes wrong, the pH-meter or the glas sensor ?

Comment: @Maurice some reddish substance appeared on the inner of the glass sensor (pretty sure it wasn't like that). I used liquid with pH=4, I stored it for about couple of weeks. The meter can't be calibrated anymore, always the same value.

Comment: @Buttonwood I uploaded images.

Comment: This is still not precise enough, what is the liquid you used? You should disassemble the electrode and clean it from the inside if possible. These glass electrodes sometimes have built-in salt bridges maybe it got contaminated there, but based on the picture the damage is more likely due to the long soaking. Probably something absorbed on its surface (glass membrane on the bottom), hindering its functionality. It is most likely you have to buy a new one, this one seems hopeless. You can try soaking it in dilute mineral acids. Also these liquids are for calibration not for storage.

Comment: It may be colloidal silver, coming from the Ag/AgCl electrode. Who knows ? Does it modify the performance of the pH-meter ? If it does not, why don't you ignore this trouble ?

Comment: @Maurice forgot to say, it does affect the performance, as you can see on the display it's always shows 1 since even if I turn calibration screw.

Comment: @Andrew Kovács I left it in one of the liquids used for calibration as it has pH=4 (distilled water with calibrating powder), because in the manual it is said to store the device in a liquid with pH=4.

Comment: There must be something that you do not mention. The display simply cannot always show $1$.

Comment: @Maurice really, how so?

Comment: I've never heard of storing a pH meter in a pH 4 solution, but I haven't used that many. I've always stored the pH probe in a KCl solution.

Comment: @user137 what is pH of your KCl solution, why KCl?

Comment: I assume the pH is neutral. The concentration is 4 M KCl. That's always been what the manufacturer suggested.

Comment: @user137 I've just found a mentioning that instead of KCl a solution with pH=4 can be used, the description under the 3rd link: https://duckduckgo.com/?t=canonical&q=store+ph-meter+in+distelled+water&ia=web

Comment: @Andrew Kovács I added a new picture of disassembled device, is it salt bridges you mentioned ? Look like those red stuff spilled from the upper part, because there is yellow trail going from the top.